# Where does matter come from?

Tags: particle-physics, mass, big-bang

I admit, it's been a few years since I've studied physics, but the following question came to me when I was listening to a talk by Lawrence Krauss.

Is there any knowledge of from where matter that exists today originated? I recall that the law of conservation of mass asserts that matter cannot be created nor destroyed, but surely the matter we see today had to be created at some point? Perhaps I am applying this law in the wrong fashion.

The reason I ask, is because Krauss mentioned that the elements of organic matter where created in stars, not at the beginning of time (whenever that may have been), but I ask, where did the building blocks for these elements arise? Were they too created in stars? If so, from where did their constituent building blocks come?

Please forgive me if this off topic, it is my first post on this particular stackexchange site. Thank you.

Comment: The most "intuitive" (non-mathematical) style of answer I've noticed, in relation to Beska's earlier comment, is that matter is created by the gravitational field, thru separation of particles from anti-particles (before they've had time to spiral into each other and "annihilate" each other--actually, to disintegrate each other into smaller particles) during such macro-scale processes as the gravitational collapse of stars that have expended their nuclear fuel and consequently lack radiation pressure to resist such collapse.  This seems consistent with "cooling" effects of gravity in general.

Comment: Why I've posted the above as a comment is because, although it seems consistent with cooling effects of gravity, it doesn't answer such deeper parts of the question as where the gravitational field came from, etc., which gets into such unverifiable possibilities as a past-eternal existence of star-like objects on larger &/or smaller scales.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The law of conservation of mass is only valid in the classical limit. More in general, the combination of mass and energy is conserved, as they can be exchanged under certain conditions $E=mc^2$.

In very simplified terms, it is currently understood that, initially, possibly only energy was present. Then this energy started to partially change into mass, forming first *quarks* and *electrons* (mostly). Then heavier particles. Finally, once the universe cooled down a bit more, the first atoms started to form through the aggregation of the particles. It is calculated that atoms would be split between hydrogen and helium with a 3:1 ratio - these are the two lightest atoms.

This was enough to create the first generation of stars, which with fusion and with their dying blast generated the heavier elements that build life.

This explains the currently understood principle of nucleogenesis - if you are instead more interested in how and why energy is changed into mass, and what is the nature of mass, then space_cadet's answer gives you a quick overlook of the hypotheses that are being studied.

Comment: This is correct but you fail to mention the difficult corollary problem: given that pair creation processes are symmetric in Baryon and Lepton numbers, why is the observed universe almost entirely devoid of *anti-matter*? (To which there are no final answers as yet. CP violation may play a part.)

Comment: "only energy was present" -> um, this part is horribly wrong. Initially (and always) there were some particles. The closer to Big Bang the higher the temperature and more massive particles you'll get. In particular, there was certainly quark-gluon plasma and a soup of heavier particles (most of which we probably don't know yet). One also needs to take into account the restoration of electroweak symmetry and perhaps grand unification. There were also lots of micro-BH and going even further probably other amusing objects of quantum gravity.

Comment: @dmckee: I left out that part purposefully. It's irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @marek: My understanding is that initially the conditions of the big bang were too hot to have any non-virtual particles. Is this the "horribly wrong" assumption?

Comment: @Sklivvz: that is not horribly wrong but it's something completely different than what you have written first. You wrote "only energy was present". And what about momentum and charge? :-) Anyway, to make it more complete, temperature only disrupts stable structures. Like if you start with normal things around us, you'd first ionize atoms then destabilize nuclei and finally you'd free up quarks from the protons and neutrons. But it stops there because quarks are elementary (at least as far as we know).

Comment: @Marek: I've added a "possibly". Honest question: quarks are elementary - but can't they be produced by pair generation like anything else? Because if they can't, then I understand your point.

Comment: @Sklivvz: perhaps I should make it clearer that when I talk about quarks I don't necessarily mean particle approximation. At some point it's better to view them as just fluctuations in the quark field (which is what they really are). But the quark field itself is real (the same way EM field or electron field is) and it's not a "pure energy" at all.

Comment: @Sklivvz: also, that edit didn't help at all. Perhaps you didn't get my objection when I mentioned charge and momentum. I am not sure what normal people mean by energy (perhaps photons?) but for me it's just one of huge number of parameters describing properties of a physical system. So your sentence makes no sense to me.

Comment: @Marek: agreed. I think that the OP was talking about particles when they specified "matter". By "pure energy" I mean the ratio between mass and energy was totally towards energy (no particles).

Comment: @Marek: I read your comment, but the OP is about where matter comes from, not where charge or momentum comes from. It's basically, imho, a question about nucleosynthesis. Also, I am trying to keep the answer simple.

Comment: @Sklivvz: ratio between mass and energy measures just how relativistic the particle is. The protons in LHC don't stop being protons just because they carry lot of energy. Or did you mean something else by that ratio?

Comment: @Sklivvz: well, the question could also be understood as where does mass come from and an elaborate discussion of Higgs boson and binding strong energy in nucleus would be in order. So I am not quite sure what OP's intentions were.

Comment: @Marek: yes I think that's the fundamental point. Except I tried to give a very very high level overview - also because i realize that I don't understand Higgs' mechanism well enough.

Comment: @Sklivvz, thank you very much for you answer. If I understand correctly, there was primarily energy in the universe, some of which has since been converted into mass as we see today? I've been reading through the comments, and I see some arguments that I do not fully understand. To address Marek's comment, my primary intention was to really find what was the first observable/quantifiable "thing" to exist in the universe, and to see if such of thing was assumed to always exist, or to have popped into existence from nothing, or what have you. I just assumed matter would be this "thing" but...

Comment: I see now that it may as well have been pure energy, (if I am reading this correctly.) I see that I have much more to study to begin to understand this even in a handwavey sense.

Comment: This hints at the right physics, but the details are muddled. It doesn't make sense to talk about "only energy" being present; rather, there was a hot plasma of photons, electrons, quarks, gluons, and other particles. At the earliest times we have good evidence and understanding of, these were a plasma with a temperature on the order of 10 MeV. As it cooled, the plasma wasn't hot enough to split nuclei into free quarks and gluons. Nucleons formed then, as you mention. But before that, there was plenty of matter around, with more baryons than antibaryons (for unknown reasons).

Comment: Also, conservation of mass is valid in the *nonrelativistic* limit, not the classical one.

Comment: There is no such thing as "pure energy" whatever that means. Might as well call it "pure ectoplasm" while you're at it. In the context of modern cosmology you have to mention CP violation and the other two Sakharov conditions if you going to speak of the "origin of matter". Nucleogenesis itself doesn't tell you anything about the origin of electrons, protons or neutrinos. Those are the inputs for nucleogenesis. But where did these "inputs" arise from? Is there a simple, self-consistent explanation for *their* presence?

Comment: "possibly only energy, then quarks and electrons. Quarks and electrons are also energy! The statement is thus meaningless. The above is intended as an explanaotion for my downvote.

Answer (score 12):

the conservation of energy is violated in cosmology - in all situations described by general relativity in which the time-translational symmetry of the "background" is broken. That's clearly the case of the Big Bang, too.

Again: By Noether's theorem, the conservation of energy is linked to the time-translational symmetry (the properties of the Universe don't depend on time) which is broken in an expanding Universe.

So one can see that the total energy/mass of the Universe is not conserved in time. In particular, the "dust" with zero pressure has a conserved total energy/mass. However, the energy carried by radiation - such as photons - decreases as $1/a$ - inverse linear size of the Universe - because the wavelength gets larger as well, which decreases the energy of each quantum.

On the contrary, the energy/mass carried by the dark energy is increasing with the volume because the energy density is constant - that's why dark energy is the normal realization is known as the cosmological constant. The density is constant but the volume of space is growing: the total energy is growing, too.

It is very likely that the huge mass of the Universe around us was created by inflation. During inflation, there was also a nonzero "dark energy" - energy density of the vacuum - which was constant while the volume of space was exponentially growing. This created lots of energy, and at the very end, a big part of the energy (kinetic energy of the inflaton which is proportional to the total energy etc.) was converted to ordinary particles that eventually gave rise to the galaxies etc.

So the exponentially large mass of the Universe is a large, unnatural number, but this unnatural number is actually explained by inflation. As Alan Guth, the main father of inflation, said, the Universe is the ultimate free lunch.

Best wishes
Lubos

Comment: @ Luboš Motl. This is by far the best answer out of the three, not sure why it does not have more votes :(

Comment: @stringpheno: Possibly because the difficulty of contents are far beyond the level of the original question.  It may be correct, but it's not clear to me that the original question asker will have gained anything from it.  (Not that I am claiming that I could do half as well.)

Comment: This answer seems consistent with Lubos Motl's support for the Poincare recurrence theorem, which keeps us from asking "why" until our jaws fall off....

Answer (score 9):

The origin of matter is a major problem in modern physics. Sure we have a *description* in terms of the Standard Model of particle interactions, but that is simply an empirical framework built upon observation. There is no compelling reason, for instance, why the gauge group of the SM should be $ SU(3)\times SU(2) \times U(1) $ and not any other. Grand Unified Theories (GUT) attempt to provide an answer which seemingly complicates the issue further by suggesting bigger groups $SO(5), SO(10), \ldots$ which can contain all three families of particles.

Certain streams of contemporary research appear to favor an alternative and perhaps simpler approach, one that was favored by Einstein and Wheeler among others - that matter is simply another aspect of geometry. The paper of Einstein and Rosen which is commonly cited as the source of the notion of wormholes, was *in fact* an attempt to provide an explanation for particles as topological defects in the vacuum.

Anyhow, all of this sounds pretty technical. To simplify the notion greatly the viewpoint favored by approaches such as Non-Commutative Geometry, LQG and (IMHO) String Theory is that particles are topological defects in a background geometry. If you think of geometry as a sheet then these defects can be thought of as punctures in this sheet. How such punctures can join up and interact should be governed by simple rules and one would hope these rules will yield the S.M. in a suitable coarse-grained approximation.

---

**Edit:** Changing some wording in 2nd para to something a little less **absolute** in response to comments by @matt and others.

Comment: Up-voted. I don't really know how popular of a viewpoint this is, but it's one that I've always found strikingly beautiful. Also worth mention (though it's similar to the mechanism in LQG, it's more appealing to condensed matter folks) is the string-net condensate of Wen and Levin.

Comment: Thanks @wsc. And yes, this perspective is completely in line with Wen's string-net paradigm. When Wen (pun intended) gave a talk some years back I remember thinking - "this guy's going to win the nobel prize". At the end of the day, I strongly believe, that dynamics of LQG will be understood only in the light of condensed matter.

Comment: What do you call it when someone votes down without giving a reason? Downvote-and-run (as in hit-and-run)?

Comment: @space_cadet: "Hit-n-run downvotes" has some currency.

Comment: Sure they do. I have nothing against them. They just defeat the purposes of discussion.

Comment: Regarding string theory: various particles are just excitations of the strings so your statement amounts to saying that strings are topological defects. Even if this view could somehow be made correct (e.g. by interpreting open string attached to a brane as topological torus) I don't believe anyone holds such a view or that it is in any way useful.

Comment: "I don't believe anyone holds such a view or that it is in any way useful" ... but that's exactly my job @Marek :) I'm not saying that strings themselves are defects, but that when they wrap and coil up forming manifolds with various topologies, that *those* can be considered as defects with respect to a uniform background geometry.

Comment: @space_cadet, thanks for this answer, I appreciate the mathematical description you've given, as I'm more a math student than a physics one.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by saying that bigger groups "contain all three families" of particles. The groups contain only gauge bosons; each generation of particles we know fits into some representation of these groups, but the generations are not unified. Also, I absolutely do not agree that research is "abandoning" field-theoretic ideas, which if nothing else are valid descriptions of low-energy physics. It's not at all clear to me in what sense either string theory or noncommutative geometry imply that matter is topological defects.

Comment: Each one of your point being absolutely valid, my answer was directed at a less specialized audience. Now to your questions. 1. The hope behind Lisi's $E8% theory (no @marek Garrett Lisi is not a crackpot) was that it contained three copies (or "generations") of leptons and quarks. Apparently Jacques Distler has shown that this is not the case. But that is what is meant by "family unification". 2. I didn't say anything about abandoning field-theory ideas. I was speaking of the GUT approaches based on larger and larger groups. 3. This is too big to tackle in a comment. Maybe I'll add an edit.

Comment: Your statement was about what GUTs attempt to do. They don't attempt to unify families. The fact that Garrett Lisi does is neither here nor there; I'm not going to argue about the definition of "crackpot," but his theory made little sense and rather than try to understand the obvious criticisms he seems to keep writing papers on the same thing. At any rate, I think this site should have answers involving accepted physics, of which GUTs are an example and whatever Lisi is doing isn't.

Comment: On the second point, I guess I was misreading you. But I still don't agree that GUTs are being abandoned. There's not a huge amount of active research on GUTs, because the underlying ideas have already been worked out.  But unification of gauge couplings remains one of the most compelling reasons to hope that supersymmetry will be found at the TeV scale. Whether new physics can be fit into a GUT will definitely be something that people will be thinking about a lot when (let's hope) the LHC discovers new physics.

Comment: "At any rate, I think this site should have answers involving accepted physics, of which GUTs are an example and whatever Lisi is doing isn't." - @Matt at best that sounds chauvinistic and at worst it sounds like censorship. Clearly you're speaking to someone who believes strongly in the general direction that Lisi's research is headed in. Given only his papers on arXiv (and ignoring his personal life) it would appear that he is a serious scientist. I've noticed this sentiment about Lisi's work expressed before on physics.se and it troubled me then and it troubles me now.

Comment: On the GUT issue ... ok, I'll happily abandon the word *abandon* in favor of something more neutral. GUTs do provide a nice picture and if you happen to have faith in them then I'm surprised that you find Lisi's work unappealing. I would think that $E_8$ being the largest exceptional lie group is a triumphant culmination of the GUT perspective. Or maybe I just don't know what I'm talking about :)

Comment: Lastly coming back to your question as to "*in what sense [do] either string theory or non-commutative geometry imply that matter is topological defects?*". I'll let 't Hooft tackle this one. He does a much better job than I can :) [Reference](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2009IJMPA..24.3243T) Of course, this work is somewhat hand-wavy in character but so was 't Hooft's 1992 paper on the Holographic Principle, and look how that one turned out!

Comment: @space_cadet: I don't think this is right place to discuss Lisi but a note is in order: I don't know whether he is crackpot but his $E_8$ theory makes no sense and was criticized by many outstanding physicists. I don't like how you call Matt either chauvinistic or a censor. In science theory is either right (for the time being) or wrong. Some of the theories are just bound to be wrong and this is one of them. Why do you have problem with that? Of course, this comment box can't address Lisi's theory. Try asking a question, I'd be happy to provide an answer as to why his theory can't work ;-)

Comment: I have no problems with a theory being right or wrong. But dismissing a scientist, **with a credible research history**, simply because Jacques Distler or some other deity has proclaimed them to be a heretic is kind of Dark-Ages, don't you think? Besides you've  finally given me motivation to get together everything I have on $E_8$. Oh, I can't wait. That rhymes! If only John Baez was on this site I wouldn't have to spend so much time defending Lisi.

Comment: @ Matt: People promoting their favourite exotica instead of sticking to mainstream ideas is one of the failure modes of this type of effort (I am sure you could think about other such examples). Not sure what is the solution, but people more committed than myself should probably think about this.

Comment: @moshe - only time will what is or is not the true value of "exotica". A quote by this guy named Gandhi comes to mind: "First they ignore you, then they ridicule you, then they fight you, then you win". We're at stage two right now in the E8 business, it seems. Only two more to go. Cheers!

Comment: I was not referring to E8 which I could not care less about, just to your original answer. When a non-expert comes and ask a question, I'll let him know what is known with near certainty (the answer to this question has probably to do with reheating).    I also like the idea of matter from geometry, and Wheeler's geons and all the rest, but the fact is that this idea currently plays no role in accepted mainstream theories, and in most research directions to extend them. That may change in the future, at which point it would be legitimate to include it in an answer.

Comment: @moshe - I did not mention Wheeler's geons in my answer. I was referring to far more recent models such as the braid model of Bilson-Thompson. On another note, I'll include whatever **I** feel is legitimate in an answer. You are free to disagree and down-vote, and if you wish to dismiss a viewpoint as out of bounds for discussion before you've even had a chance to look at the details is your prerogative.

Comment: Both Lisi's and the braid models you mention (both of which I am actually quite familiar with) are works in progress which may or not pan out in the end. I have no problem with that, presenting them as an established fact is what I was having a problem with.

Comment: I say this in my answer about these approaches - "the viewpoint **favored** by approaches such as Non-Commutative Geometry, LQG ...". That is clearly not a statement of established fact, and is also more a statement of my **personal** opinion. In any case, I appreciate and understand your concerns and will try my best to keep them in mind.

Comment: We are both in the same boat, I am also enthusiastic about what I do, and have to control the natural urge to share that enthusiasm by overstating things. I just know from experience how fast this can degenerate into a discussion focused in its entirety on great sounding but half baked ideas.

Comment: @moshe - that is why I trust you, and others on this site,  to *intensively interrogate* any statements I make!